# how to solve this issue and run npm install?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to run npm install so I can do yarn start to deploy the project to was but it gives me an error.
Anyone here can help me understand what is going on and how to solve it?

The Error output here:

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for proto@git+https://github.com/ArtistCrowdfundExchange/proto.git (null) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for proto@git+https://github.com/ArtistCrowdfundExchange/proto.git (null) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/youmnasalloum/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneEiauOJ/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/youmnasalloum/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-cloneEiauOJ/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/youmnasalloum/.npm/_logs/2022-04-01T11_16_23_452Z-debug-0.log
```

The package.json content here:

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "repository": "https://github.com/ArtistCrowdfundExchange/user",
  "author": "Oghogho Odemwingie",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.13",
    "typescript": "4.5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node index.ts",
    "test": "echo no tests yet"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.41.0",
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.3.7",
    "aws4": "^1.11.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cuid": "^2.1.8",
    "jose": "3",
    "mongoose": "6.1.8",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.29",
    "proto": "git+https://github.com/ArtistCrowdfundExchange/proto#playground",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the "proto" repository exist and do you have access to it?

Comment: yes it exists and yes it is a repository in the same organization but how do make sure I have access to it in the terminal?
*the senior just left his job so maybe I need to make sure using the terminal could help me?

Comment: You could try to clone the repository using `git clone https://github.com/ArtistCrowdfundExchange/proto.git`, if that doesn't work you may need to configure GitHub to allow access from your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Same as @Mustafa Jawed and then make sure you are in the **correct folder**! if you use terminal use "ls" to see the content
and go to to correct dictionary by for example "cd myExampleJsApp".

Answer (score 0):

Delete `package-lock.json` and rerun the `npm i`.

If this doesn't work then remove the `node_modules` and reinstall it.

Comment: I don't have package-lock.json in the project and I remove node_modules but when I try npm install command gives me this error

Comment: how to reinstall node_modules after i remove it?